# How do you select multiple rows in one table, but only one row in another?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Here is an example of what I mean:
Table Actions has columns ActionMaker, ActionReciever, and Details.
Table Profiles has a column ID, which corresponds to ActionMaker and ActionReciever.
I want to select a row from actions and also the corresponding IDs for both Action columns.
I need to be able to know which ID belongs to which role in the action.

Comment: how is the data laid out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join the `Profiles` table twice - once by `ActionMarket` and once by `ActionReceiver`

```
SELECT *
FROM Actions A
INNER JOIN Profiles P1
    ON A.ActionMaker = P1.ID
INNER JOIN Profiles P2
    ON A.ActionReciever= P2.ID
```

Comment: Yes, just test it. Then using the aliases`P1` and `P2`, you can select only the columns you need and named it as you like. For exmaple, `SELECT P1.MyColumnName AS ActionMarketName, P2.MyColumName as ActionReciverName`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Joining is definitely what I needed.  Being that one of the IDs in the Actions table can be null, I used left join to grab those rows as well.  Thank's for pointing me to joining!